# Parameter passing to std::accumulate

Tags: c++, algorithm, lambda

My reference is to the example provided under the following:

[std::accumulate](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate)

I am trying to constrast the following usage of std::next in the example,

```
std::string s = 
  std::accumulate(
    std::next(v.begin()), 
    v.end(),
    std::to_string(v[0]), // start with first element
    dash_fold
  );
```

with the usage example provided for [std::next](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/next)

Given that in the referred to example for std::accumulate usage, the following is the signature of `dash_fold`:

```
auto dash_fold = [](std::string a, int b){...}
```

I am assuming that the construct `std::next(v.begin()), v.end(), std::to_string(v[0]...`
above should produce

`int, string`

which is reversing the order of parameters that `dash_fold` expects; is this understanding correct? Or am I missing something?

TIA

Comment: Could you post a [mcve] and the error that makes you think about the reversed argument order? It works well here https://godbolt.org/z/9b7K8YKr1

Comment: @273K rather I am trying to understand how it works....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The referenced manual is very detailed.

```
constexpr T accumulate( InputIt first, InputIt last, T init,
                        BinaryOperation op );
```

`T` in your case is the type of `std::to_string(v[0])`, is `std::string`.

**op**:

> ```
> Ret fun(const Type1 &a, const Type2 &b);
> ```
>
> The type `Type1` must be such that an object of type `T` can be implicitly converted to `Type1`.

`Type1` must be such that an object of type `std::string` can be implicitly converted to `Type1`. If the first parameter type is `int`, then `std::string` cannot be implicitly converted to `int` - fail. If the first parameter type is `std::string`, then it works well.